# How to label figure 1a and 1b as Figure 1?

Tags: floats

I have figure 1a, 1b, 1c and I want to refer them as figure 1. How would I do it. I have used `\ContinuedFloat` to number the figures as 1a, 1b and 1c.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the `subcaption` package, but you did not provide any compilable document, so this is a guess only

Comment: Place a `\caption{combined description}\label{fig:combined}`    and refer to the combined label.  Maybe.

Comment: @Johannes_B: `\caption` would increase the figure counter however, so the reference from `\ref{fig:combined}` would give something like `2` etc.

Comment: The usage of `\ContinuedFloat` here seems logically wrong, however.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer By default,  `\thesubfloat` would not have the parent counter. As it stands, the question cannot be answered due to a lack of information. Everything is just guesswork.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That's true... if there's a subfloat counter... and it's true about the guesswork